# How to change the textbox text in class other than Form1.cs in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

So I have class DigitButton the NormalDigitClick gets called when a button is pressed. and it calls the appendNumber.

```
public class DigitButton
{
    public static void NormalDigitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        Model model = new Model();
        model.appendNumber(button.Text);
    }
}
```

The appnedNumber() appends the number and am trying to reflect this number in the textbox in setTextboxVslue() but textbox is not showing anything. Not sure what is going wrong.

```
public class Model :Form1
{
    public static string textBoxValue;

    public void appendNumber(string valueToBeAppended)
    {
        if (textBoxValue == "0")
        {
            textBoxValue = "";
        }
        textBoxValue = textBoxValue + valueToBeAppended;
        setTextboxValue(textBoxValue);
    }
    private void setTextboxValue(string textBoxValue)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBoxValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accessing the Form that is opened in your application. You are creating a new instance of Model and then you don't even show it. You need to get the instance of the Model form that is already opened in your application. Replace the following two lines:

```
Model model = new Model();
model.appendNumber(button.Text);
```

with the following line:

```
(Application.OpenForms["Model"] as Model).appendNumber(button.Text);
```

Comment: No. I don't have multiple forms. I have single form (Form1.cs). I don't know why the appended value is not visible in  textbox.

Comment: :- Yep Thanks, I needed to get the form which is already opened. Model was not my form. so here's how I used it. (Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1).updateText(button.Text);

Comment: Glad to help. Can you please up-vote and mark as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

whenever appendTextbox call. create new instance (Model) so the value will not change

try something like this,

```
    Model model = new Model();
```

Change

```
    Model model = (Model1)button.Parent;
```